# Cost of cheapest Azure B2C offering?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I understand that Azure B2C is free for up to 50,000 users. But as soon as I want to add in ROLES, I have to take out a subscription. These subscriptions are prohibitively expensive (P1 and P2). Am I right in my assumption that AZURE is really only for big business. Not having roles is like a car without wheels!

If anyone can shed some light ? We are a very small startup that cannot afford these rates.
Thanks

- I have looked at Auth0, but their support is not great and they don't cater for Blazor in their docs (The only article they have is out of date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by roles?

B2C does not handle roles but AAD does.

As per [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/security/business/identity-access/azure-active-directory-pricing), role-based access control is covered by the free level.

B2C is free for the first 50,000 MAU but you do have to pay for MFA.

"A flat fee of $0.03 is billed for each SMS/Phone-based multi-factor authentication attempt."

You do have to link B2C to an Azure [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use AAD, can a user register themselves  in my applications, or do I have to do that as the admin?

Comment: In AAD, use external identities. In B2C, use a sign up profile.

Comment: SMS fee seems too high